# Querying Notion database with formula field returns incorrect formula results

Tags: formula, notion-api, notion

I am using Google Apps Script to query data from a Notion database and create calendar events in my Google Calendar.

I have come across some odd behavior that I can't figure out.

My Notion database has one entry for each event. Each event has a start and end date (stored in a single date field). I have some formulas that use the start and end dates to calculate different fields (ex: how many years have elapsed since July 1, 2020). When I look at the Notion page I see one value, and when I query the database via the API I get a different value, but only for some entries.

In the two images below note the entry called "Peds Neuro"
[See the Notion database here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7Z1A.png)
[See the Debug output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWBQX.png)

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I am experiencing the same for an automation that relies on the data.
I assume that the recent updates to the formula-feature has introduced a regression.

Comment: Can you please provide the formula for `Period`?

Comment: There can be differences if the formula is based on dates without time. When you access the details from API, they are usually based on UTC. But on UI, they can be timezone specific. So if you are accessing at a time where for UTC date is ahead or behind your timezone date, it can cause such issues.

Comment: very interesting!
Here is the formula for period:
`min(max(floor((dateBetween(dateStart(prop("Date")), dateAdd(fromTimestamp(1593576000000), prop("PGY") - 1, "years"), "days") + if(day(dateAdd(fromTimestamp(1593576000000), prop("PGY") - 1, "years")) % 7 < 4, day(dateAdd(fromTimestamp(1593576000000), prop("PGY") - 1, "years")) % 7 - 1, day(dateAdd(fromTimestamp(1593576000000), prop("PGY") - 1, "years")) % 7 - 8)) / 28), 0), 12) + 1`

Is there a way to make the formula timezone agnostic?

Comment: From your formula I can not see if `Date` or `PGY` are rollups from relations. I still thought I let you know that I have just received following response from the support at Notion:

> We have identified a bug related to API not returning values of formula when relations have been used in it. I believe your API calls are also affected by this.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am not sure if that bug affects me because I don't have a rollup.
Here is the formula for PGY: `dateBetween(dateStart(prop("Date")), parseDate("2020-07-01"), "years") + 1`
And date is just a date range without a time (or timezone).

But it also doesn't make sense to me why the result of the formula would depend on the timezone of the API called because I make no reference to the current time.

Comment: For what it's worth, I resolved this by replacing the fromTimestamp() function with the parseDate() equivalent. I'm assuming this means the discrepancy has to do with a timezone issue that I don't want to bother with right now.

Comment: @haynzz any way for me to +1 this bug fix request with Notion? It's affecting me as well.